# How to make the following optimization problem format?

Tags: equations, align

I am using `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}`.
In this document class, how can I make the following optimization problem?

[image: Opt]

---

If I use `align` environments to make the aligned Consts. and Exts., the labels are (1), (2), and so on.

For sub-labels, such as (1a), (1b), and so on, I tried to use `maxi!` in `optidef` package and `IEEEeqnarray` in `IEEEtran` package. In these case, the alignments of Consts. and Exts. are broken.

Is there any method to make the optimization problem have the above formation?

---

Above all, I am sorry for posting a vague question.
Hence, I've just added two images more what I want to make finally.

[image: final]

[image: final2]

Actually, the problem is not meaningful. I made them by powerpoint to show what I want to make. If the horizontal space is enough I want to use the below, otherwise I want to use the above one. I think `egreg`'s answer is the easiest way, but it looks bad when the lengths of the left hand side in constriants are much different (because it aligns some symbols using `&=`, `&\ne`, `&\le`, and so on.) I tried to use `array` environment, but it does not give sub-labels.

Comment: Can you please make an approximate example? Not everybody knows what “Const.” and “Ext.” mean.

Comment: The constraints can be an equation, e.g., `\lVert{\bm{x}_i-\bm{y}_j\rVert`, the first extra can be a condition, e.g., `\forall i\in\mathcal{A}`, and the second extra can be another condition, e.g., `\forall j\in\mathcal{B}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use `IEEEeqnarray`, which is directly available with `IEEEtran` and can be used with other classes by loading `IEEEtrantools`.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{IEEEtrantools} % don't load it with IEEEtran

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{s,rCl'rCl'rCl}
maximize   & \IEEEeqnarraymulticol{9}{l}{x^2+x+1} \\
subject to & X_{ij} &=&   Y_{j} & i &=& 1,\dots,m & j &=& 1,\dots,n \\
           & p_k    &\le& 3     & 1 &\le& k \le 27
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

`s` means a textual column, `,` for a narrow space, `'` for quad space; `r` for a right aligned math column, `C` for a centered one with relation symbols,l` for a left aligned math column.

Comment: Is there a method to make the 1st and 2nd rows aligned at center, but the rows from the 3rd row aligned left?

Comment: Thank you, very much. This is almost exactly what I want. I put my code myself

Answer (score 2):

May be this could help (by using the `[subequations]` enviroment

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{subequations}
        \begin{align}
    & \underset{X}{\max}
    & & \mathrm{trace}(X) \\
    & \text{subject to}
    & & X_{ij} = M_{ij}, \; (i,j) \in \Omega, \\
    &&& X \succeq 0.
\end{align}
    \end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Incorporating @BambOo's suggestion

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}
\begin{document}
    \begin{subequations}
        \begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
            & \underset{X}{\max}
            ~~\mathrm{trace}(X) \\
            &X_{ij} = M_{ij}, \; (i,j) \in \Omega, \\
            &X \succeq 0.
        \end{empheq}
    \end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

gives:

[image]

Comment: You can replace the `align` wiht an`empheq` environment (requires to load the `empheq` package) with the environment parameters `[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}` to display a big brace covering the three equations.

Comment: @BambOo Thanks for the tip. But, the user doesnt seem to be much interested in with the braces :D (hence, I ignored it) Because, the square braces the user metions seems to me some sort of format description, rather than the braces as a part of equation itself.

Comment: Yes, indeed he doesn't mention this, it is just a quite common way of formatting constrained optimization problem (LCPs for instance)

Comment: @BambOo Ohh, yeah! I get your point now.

Comment: Just a quick remark: I’d suggest to replace `\mathrm{trace}` with `\operatorname{trace}`—unless, of course, you prefer to go with `\DeclareMathOperator`.  See the manual of the `amsmath` package, section 5.

Comment: …And also—sorry, I had overlooked that—`\underset{X}{\max}` with `\max_{X}`…

Comment: @GuM Thats okay, and thanks for the tip wrt the operator usage!

Comment: @RaajaG, actually now the "subject to" is meant by the brace since the equations now form a system.

Comment: @BambOo edited the answer :)

Comment: @RaajaG, another small edit, i do not thing the large spacing is relevant anymore thanks to the brace, see [the formatting for LCPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_complementarity_problem)

Comment: @BambOo I think now its okay!

Answer (score 0):

Based on `egreg`'s answer, I made the code fit to my situation.

```
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{c'l'l'l"}
    \IEEEyesnumber\label{Problem}\IEEEyessubnumber*
    \maximize_{\framebox[2.2cm]{}}
    &\IEEEeqnarraymulticol{3}{l}{\framebox[5cm]{}} \label{Objective}\\
    \subjto
    &\framebox[2cm]{},  &\framebox[1.5cm]{},    &\framebox[1cm]{},\label{Const1}\\
    &\framebox[2cm]{},  &\framebox[1.5cm]{},    &\framebox[1cm]{},\label{Const2}\\
    &\framebox[2cm]{},  &\framebox[1.5cm]{},    &\framebox[1cm]{},\label{Const3}\\
    &\framebox[2cm]{},  &\framebox[1.5cm]{},\label{Const4}\\
    &\framebox[2cm]{},  &\framebox[1.5cm]{},    &\framebox[1cm]{},\label{Const5}\\
    &\framebox[2cm]{},  &\framebox[1.5cm]{},\label{Const6}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
```

[image: first]

and

```
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{c'l'l'l"}
    \IEEEyesnumber\label{Problem}\IEEEyessubnumber*
    \maximize_{\framebox[2.2cm]{}}
    &\IEEEeqnarraymulticol{3}{l}{\framebox[5cm]{}} \label{Objective}\\
    \subjto\notag\\
    \IEEEeqnarraymulticol{2}{l}{\framebox[2.6cm]{},}    &\framebox[2.5cm]{},    &\framebox[1.7cm]{},\label{Const1}\\
    \IEEEeqnarraymulticol{2}{l}{\framebox[2.6cm]{},}    &\framebox[2.5cm]{},    &\framebox[1.7cm]{},\label{Const2}\\
    \IEEEeqnarraymulticol{2}{l}{\framebox[2.6cm]{},}    &\framebox[2.5cm]{},    &\framebox[1.7cm]{},\label{Const3}\\
    \IEEEeqnarraymulticol{2}{l}{\framebox[2.6cm]{},}    &\framebox[2.5cm]{},\label{Const4}\\
    \IEEEeqnarraymulticol{2}{l}{\framebox[2.6cm]{},}    &\framebox[2.5cm]{},    &\framebox[1.7cm]{},\label{Const5}\\
    \IEEEeqnarraymulticol{2}{l}{\framebox[2.6cm]{},}    &\framebox[2.5cm]{},\label{Const6}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
```

[image: second]